# proccess at linux ,fork value divided by zero

Tags: linux, fork

```
main()
{
    printf( "%d\n" , 1/fork() );
}
```

by running this app my output is: 0.

I know that at parent fork value is number ,and at Son the value is 0.

So why don't I get any problem dividing 1/0 ?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, the 1/0 Arithmetic Exception do occur, but it just do not print out in the console.

set core file size to unlimited you will see the core file

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

And use gdb you can see the Arithmetic Exception

```
$ gdb a.out core
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is transforming your code into more elementary steps

(you could pass the `-fdump-tree-all` option to GCC, or use [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) graphical [probe](http://gcc-melt.org/index.html#probe_id) to look into some intermediate GCC representations)

So bascially the compiler is transforming your code into something like

```
 int main()
 {
   int t1 = fork();
   int t2 = 1 / t1;
   printf("%d\n", t2);
 }
```

So if `t1` gets `0` (in the child process), the assignment to `t2` is an undefined behavior, which usually crashes with a division by zero (i.e. a `SIGFPE` asynchronous signal), and the `printf` is not reached.

Probably, on a [PowerPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerpc) processor where you can make a division by zero which does not crash, the behavior (still undefined) would be different.

BTW, you should run your program with `strace -f` to understand what syscalls & signals are involved.